Adding bump to a matcap material
:)
I'm trying to make a stylized wood material, using just matcaps (without lighting). Is there any way to add bump or normal map to this material? I attached my material setup. Thanks!

See https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/output/material.html#Displacement

You can plug any normal map (RGB data) or bump map (BW data) and their respective normal/bump map nodes into the Material Output node's displacement socket. It will used as bump by default and you can also change the material settings to use it as displacement or both.
I think you need to put a displacement node just before, but i can't check right now.
See those few manual pages:

Material Output Node
Material Settings
Displacement and Bump

